# What is the difference between Stop Tracking and Discard File in git SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I wanted to know what the difference is between discarding a file and and stop tracking a file in git using source-tree. If I deleted a file in my updated code and I want that file deleted on the repository too should I mark it as stop tracking or should I discard it during the commit process

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In SourceTree, selecting "discard" on a file just throws away your local changes; stop tracking removes it from the repository. However, as long as you have deleted the file on your local drive, and you can see that deletion in the "Staged Files" section of SourceTree, it will be deleted in the repository as well when you commit.

Comment: How do you do the equivalent from cmd prompt?   SourceTree did the job while Visual Studio and git status both acted like .sln file was modified and it was indeed not - so this "Discard" seems to have been the trick.

Comment: In the most recent version of Sourcetree **Discard** option was renamed to **Reset**

Comment: @TomStickel - the command line equivalent of SourceTree's "Discard" for a file is `git checkout path/to/some/file.sln`. You've probably already discovered this in the 4+ years since you asked, but I figured I'd answer just in case :)

Answer (score 66):

The one detail not covered by the first answer is that **Stop Tracking** does not delete the local file. It only removes it from source control.

1. If you want to keep the file locally (maybe it's a .suo file storing
   Visual Studio settings that you decide shouldn't have been in source
   control) but remove it from the repository, you should use **Stop Tracking**. After this, if you see the file listed in *Unstaged files*, you can use **right-click > Ignore...** in SourceTree to update your .gitignore file to ignore the file in future.
2. If you want to delete your file both locally and in the repository,
   you should use **Remove**. (to use the SourceTree term)
3. Finally, if you only want to revert your local changes without
   changing the repository at all, use **Discard**.

Comment: For files created by the build env (e.g. gradlew.bat), ignore is greyed out.  Remove an stop tracking ar options. The file is shown with a yellowish colour.  Any ideas? If I do Stop tracking, it comes up in red.

Comment: What does reset do?

Comment: @john-little Is it possible that you staged the addition of gradlew.bat? I found that ignore is disabled when you have staged a change, but if you unstage you can then ignore. Alternatively, is the file already under source control? If it appears yellow, that would suggest it's a change, not an addition.

Comment: @john-little Regarding your question about "reset", are you referring to an action in SourceTree? Or are you referring to the "git reset" command? If so, it is fully documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).

Comment: I tried "Stop tracking" and noticed that selected files where moved to stage area, as a normal file I'd like to commit.
what should I do, then, commit files moved to stage area? If I commit, will such action have effect on remote repository or will it influence only my local version of files? If I commit, should I push too?

Comment: @KenLyon is there a way to track the file again? I have tried `git add *` in its directory but it still was being tracked. The .gitignore file also doesn't list the file. How do I track the file again?