# Ignoring already committed files in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I am still new to git. Since I do not need my repository to be publicly available, I chose Bitbucket. As my desktop client I use Atlassian Sourcetree.

I am working on a Java project using Eclipse IDE. Just like everyone, I do not need the class files to be visible in changed files, however those files have already been committed and pulled into my remote repository.
Now I need SourceTree to not to show those class files as changed files whenever I make a change to `.java` file.

As I have understood by coming through so many questions and answers, the entry in the `.gitignore` file alone cannot simply ignore the class files since they have already been committed and pulled.
For that, as I understand, what I should do is ignore the file in source tree and commit it. Then only the entry in the `.gitignore` file would do what we need. (This is my understanding. Please correct me if I am wrong).

What my problem now is, the `ignore` option is grayed out; so as a solution for that the community suggest to first select the `Stop Tracking` option and then select the `ignore` option. But when I do Stop Tracking, no change appears.
As per the community, the file should be marked with a blue icon. But it is not in my case. Even though I didn't get change of the icon, I then tried to select the ignore option. But still it is grayed out. Even after doing these steps, when I make a change to `.java` file, the `.class` file appears in the changed files list.

What is wrong here? Why I am not getting the job done? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Adding files to `.gitignore` which are already in the repository won't do anything.  If this be the case, then you first need to `git -rm` the file, push, and afterwards add it to `.gitignore`.

Comment: thanks. HOw can I `git -rm` the entire folder which contains all the class files

Comment: Just use a wildcard, e.g. `git -rm some/path/*.java`

Comment: i get unknown option `git -rm` error

Comment: Use `git rm --cached -r foldername`

Comment: Check out `git update-index` as suggested in the second answer to this question: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2):

> What my problem now is, the ignore option is grayed out; so as a solution for that the community suggest to first select the Stop Tracking option and then select the ignore option.

According to "[What is the difference between Stop Tracking and Discard File in git SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37666172/6309)":

> You should use `Stop Tracking`.
>   After this, if you see the file listed in Unstaged files, you can use `right-click > Ignore...` in SourceTree to update your `.gitignore` file to ignore the file in future.

In your case though, instead of adding the files one by one to a `.gitignore`, adit a `.gitignore` at the root of your repo and add:

```
*.class
```

Comment: stop tracking does not make the file go into unstaged files; so that I cannot ignore it.

Comment: in my repo, i have the `.gitignore` file with `.classpath` entry in it. I think it is correct. Isn't it?

Comment: @vigamage Then switch to comand line and try (for testing) `git rm -r obj` (if your `.class` are in the folder `obj`) No need for wildcard

Answer (score 0):

Enter **git status** to display your modified code changes.then add your unwanted files in the .**gitignore** .
At last add your file and commit it.